# TFS api - candidates excluded by file extension

Tags: api, visual-studio-2012, workspace

I am trying to import a set of files into TFS using the API. The method Workspace.GetPendingChangesWithCandidates excludes files that match the globally ignored file extensions (.dll, etc). How can I get these files from the API so that I can PendAdd them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer but I think it's a kludge. You can edit the  LocalItemExclusions.config file found here: 
C:\Users\%username%\appdata\local\microsoft\team foundation\4.0\configuration\versioncontrol.

Ultimately, I think the ignored files should be overridden from the API, but I can't find such an option.

Answer (score 0):

It is an older question, but this may help others: Another way to get files recognized as candidates is to create a file called ".tfignore" within the workspace that enables globally filtered files again.

```
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

More details can be found here

[MSDN: Add files to the server - Customize which files are ignored by version control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore)